# Problema en C, no me deja introducir datos en cola de tipo char?

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, dev-c++, nodos

Tengo el problema de que cuando quiero introducir caracteres para guardarlos y mostrarlos en las colas, el programa simplemente se cierra y no realiza las funciones. Estoy aprendiendo estructuras de datos en C, necesito ayuda por favor.
He estado revisando el codigo una y otra vez pero no entiendo que es lo que pasa. Probe con hacer arreglos de una sola posicion pero tampoco me deja... No se que hacer, simplemente quiero ingresar elementos de tipo carácter a una cola y mostrarlos. Eso es todo.
Inclui las librerias stdlib.h y stdio.h , ademas como pueden observar tengo el programa organizado en un menu

```
// Ejercicio Colas
// Se requiere hacer un programa en C, que contenga el siguiente menu. 
// 1. Añadir caracteres a cola.
// 2. Mostrar elementos en la cola.
// 3. Salir

struct Nodo{
    char dato;
    Nodo *siguiente;    
};

//Prototipos de funciones
void menu();
void agregarCola(Nodo *&frente, Nodo*&fin, char dato);
void quitarCola(Nodo *&frente, Nodo *&fin, char &dato);
bool cola_vacia(Nodo *frente);

int main()
{
    menu();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
//Funciones
//Funcion menu
void menu(){
    int opc;
    char dato;
    
    Nodo *frente = NULL;
    Nodo *fin = NULL;
    
    do{
        printf("\t.:MENU:.\n");
        printf("\n1. Insertar un caracter a una cola");
        printf("\n2. Mostrar todos los elementos de la cola");
        printf("\n3. Salir");
        printf("\nOPCION: ");
        scanf("%d",&opc); 
        
        switch(opc){
            case 1: printf("\nIngrese el caracter a leer en la cola");
                    scanf("%c",dato);
                    agregarCola(frente,fin,dato);
                    break;
            case 2: printf("\nMostrando los elementos de la cola ");
                    while(frente != NULL){
                    quitarCola(frente,fin,dato);
                        if(frente != NULL){
                            printf("%c ,",dato);
                        }
                        else{
                            printf("%c .",dato);
                        }
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                    system("pause");
                    break;
                    
            case 3: break;
        }
        system("cls");
    }while(opc != 3);
        
}
void agregarCola(Nodo *&frente, Nodo*&fin, char n){
    Nodo *nuevo_nodo= new Nodo();
    
    nuevo_nodo->dato=n;
    nuevo_nodo->siguiente=NULL;
    
    if(cola_vacia(frente)){
        frente= nuevo_nodo;
    }else{
        fin->siguiente=nuevo_nodo;
    }
    fin=nuevo_nodo;
    printf("Elemento %c anadido a la cola ",n);
}

bool cola_vacia(Nodo *frente){
    if(frente=NULL){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

void quitarCola(Nodo*&frente,Nodo*&fin,char &n){
    n= frente->dato; //Asignamos a n lo que queremos eliminar
    Nodo *aux=frente;
    
    if(frente==fin){
        frente=NULL;
        fin=NULL;
    }else{
        frente=frente->siguiente;
    }
    delete aux;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primer punto al momento de realizar `scanf("%c",dato);` debes hacer `scanf("%c",&dato);` hasta donde yo sé.

Segundo punto luego de leer datos te recomiendo Limpiar el buffer, recuerda que si tienes un salto de linea por el *Enter* entonces el próximo `scanf` va leer tu salto de linea (`\n`) y no el carácter que ingreses.

Tercera recomendación, una vez resuelvas los dos primeros puntos, solo revisa la siguiente función (observación en los comentarios):

```
void agregarCola(Nodo *&frente, Nodo*&fin, char n){
    Nodo *nuevo_nodo= new Nodo();
    
    nuevo_nodo->dato=n;
    nuevo_nodo->siguiente=NULL;
    
    if(cola_vacia(frente)){
        frente= nuevo_nodo;
    }else{
        // me parece que acá se produce un error yo te recomiendo hacer un debug.
        fin->siguiente=nuevo_nodo;
    }
    fin=nuevo_nodo;
    printf("Elemento %c anadido a la cola ",n);
}
```

Espero esto te pueda orientar, la lectura del carácter se producirá con normalidad, pero esa linea de código te genera un error.

Sí no sabes hacer muy bien los debug, pinta lineas luego de cada linea para que sepas donde está tu error y luego cranealo un poco, para mi siempre fue difícil esto de punteros y direcciones de memoria.

***EDITADO*** 
Te dejo el código modificado con algunos puntos para que puedas continuar avanzando, aún tiene algunos errores pero confió en que podrás solucionarlos (como por ejemplo una vez retiras los nodos el problema tiene un volcado de memoria -creo que podrás solucionarlo)
Te dejo un enlace donde podrás ver el código funcionar con tranquilidad 
[Código C de tu Cola](https://onlinegdb.com/BJ9LUsZ9v)

Código:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Nodo {
    char dato;
    Nodo *siguiente;    
};

void menu();
void agregarCola(Nodo *&frente, Nodo *&fin, char dato);
void quitarCola(Nodo *&frente, Nodo *&fin, char &dato);
bool cola_vacia(Nodo *frente);

int main() {
    menu();
    // system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void menu(){
    int opc;
    char dato;
    
    Nodo *frente = NULL; // cola total
    Nodo *fin = NULL; // ultimo nodo de la cola
    // Asignamos memoria de la estructura Nodo a la variable frente y fin.
    frente = (struct Nodo*) malloc(sizeof(struct Nodo));
    // '\0', NULL indica el inicio o frente esta vacio, cuando sea '\0', NODO entonces ya no estará vacia
    frente -> dato = '\0'; // caracter vacio
    frente -> siguiente = NULL; // no deben tener nodos siguientes
    fin = (struct Nodo*) malloc(sizeof(struct Nodo));
    fin -> dato = '\0'; // caracter vacio
    fin -> siguiente = NULL; // no deben tener nodos siguientes
    
    do{
        printf("\t.:MENU:.\n");
        printf("\n1. Insertar un caracter a una cola");
        printf("\n2. Mostrar todos los elementos de la cola");
        printf("\n3. Salir");
        printf("\nOPCION: ");
        scanf("%d", &opc);
        
        switch(opc) {
            case 1: printf("\nIngrese el caracter a leer en la cola\n");
                    scanf(" %c", &dato); // acá colocamos " %c" el espacio en blanco es para evitar el salto de linea que debjo tu scanf opcion.
                    agregarCola(frente, fin, dato);
                    break;
            case 2: printf("\nMostrando los elementos de la cola\n");
                    while(frente != NULL){
                    quitarCola(frente, fin, dato);
                        if(frente != NULL){
                            printf("%c ,", dato);
                        }
                        else{
                            printf("%c .", dato);
                        }
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                    // system("pause");
                    break;
                    
            case 3: break;
        }
        // system("cls");
    }while(opc != 3);
        
}
void agregarCola(Nodo *&frente, Nodo *&fin, char n) {
    Nodo *nuevo_nodo = NULL; //= new Nodo();
    // Asignamos memoria.
    nuevo_nodo = (struct Nodo*) malloc(sizeof(struct Nodo));
    
    nuevo_nodo -> dato = n; // colocamos el valor n en el atributo dato del puntero nuevo_nodo
    nuevo_nodo -> siguiente = NULL; // colocamos el vaor NULL en el atributo siguiente del puntero nuevo_nodo

    if(cola_vacia(frente)) {
        frente -> siguiente = nuevo_nodo;
    } else {
        fin -> siguiente = nuevo_nodo;
    }

    fin = nuevo_nodo;
    printf("Elemento %c anadido a la cola\n", n);
}

bool cola_vacia(Nodo *frente) {
    if(frente -> siguiente == NULL && frente -> dato == '\0') {
        // la cola esta vacia
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

void quitarCola(Nodo*&frente,Nodo*&fin,char &n) {
    n = frente -> dato; // Asignamos a n lo que queremos eliminar
    Nodo *aux = frente;
    
    if(frente == fin) {
        frente = NULL;
        fin = NULL;
    } else {
        frente = frente->siguiente;
    }
    delete aux;
}
```

Comment: Hice los dos primeros pasos y sigue igual el problema.. El ultimo he tratado de ver que esta mal pero no lo encuentro, teoricamente lo que yo quiero ahi es que si el frente de la cola es nulo , es que la cola esta vacia y no tiene ningun elemento por el momento, por tanto lo que quiero es crear un nuevo nodo en el frente. Sino es asi pues el frente de la cola se moveria al nodo siguiente y elimina el nodo auxiliar. Me parece muy extraño esto teniendo en cuenta que con numeros el error no sucede..

Comment: @AgustinLyon He modificado mi comentario para darte más apoyo, espero con eso puedas avanzar un poco más. me comentas si te aclaro las dudas, sí es así espero alguna puntuación :'v

Answer (score 0):

1. Deberías definir la cola como una estructura que contenga los punteros frente y fin. Ayudaría a ver el código más claro el que te refieras a un objeto "pila" (o como lo quieras llamar) cuando lo manipules.
2. No entiendo por qué indireccionas los punteros que pasas como parámetros a las funciones (Nodo* &frente -> no tiene ningún sentido para mí si lo que estás pretendiendo es pasar a la función un puntero).
3. Tal y como te dice Diego, `scanf` espera como segundo parámetro un puntero, en este caso a `char`.
4. En C, hasta donde yo sé, no se crean instancias de una estructura con `new` como se pueda hacer en C++. Si creas estructuras dinámicas tienes que gestionar la memoria que asignas a instancias nuevas con `malloc()` y `realloc()`.
5. `delete` (que utilizas en `quitarCola`) es sintaxis de C++ no de C. Para liberar memoria que previamente has reservado con `malloc()` o `realloc()` debes usar `free()`.

malloc está definida en c como `void* malloc(size_t size)`, es decir, hay que pasarle como parámetro el tamaño total de la memoria que quieras reservar que normalmente puedes calcular con la función sizeof().

Además devuelve un puntero indeterminado, por lo que para asignarlo a una variable hay que castearlo antes al tipo que corresponda. En tu caso sería: `nuevo_nodo = (Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));`

realloc funciona parecido pero para variables que ya tienen un tamaño de memoria asignado previamente con malloc.

Comment: Me podrias indicar como en este caso serian las sustituciones con malloc y realloc? Disculpa pero es que mi profesor de programacion nos esta enseñando es a usar new() a la hora de crear los nodos

Comment: Te lo añado a la respuesta que te dí antes.